# Using a Powershell noteproperty as a text string in a variable

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I've used Invoke-Restmethod to download some data, which Powershell stores in a PSCustomObject, in a property called data.

I need to use the value of one of the items in the returned data as a variable for another command. I have managed to select-object -expand my way down to the following output from Get-Member:

```
Name        MemberType   Definition                    
----        ----------   ----------                    
Equals      Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method       int GetHashCode()             
GetType     Method       type GetType()                
ToString    Method       string ToString()             
id          NoteProperty System.Int32 id=999
```

What I need to do is grab the value of the ID noteproperty - 999 - and pass that as part of a string to a new variable, eg:

```
$newVar = "sometext" + 999 + "moretext"
```

No amount of select-string or out-string etc is helping. Scripting is not exactly my strong point so I'm not sure I'm even articulating what I want properly - apologies if this is the case!

Any assistance much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what your code and looks like, so I created the following static approximation from the description:

```
$data = New-Object PSCustomObject
$data | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name Id -Value 999
$restResponse = New-Object PSCustomObject
$restResponse | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name data -Value $data
```

Please clarify if this is not a match.  You can get the Id value as follows

```
$restResponse.data.Id
```

Assign it to another variable

```
$newVar = "sometext" + $restResponse.data.Id + "moretext"
$newVar
```

And if your REST response is a collection of data objects, iterate through them

```
$restResponse.data | Foreach-Object { "sometext" + $_.Id + "moretext" }
```

Comment: Thats done it, thank you. I think I was staring at this for too long!

Answer (score 0):

I would go for for using `$output | select *,@{n='test';e={[string]$_.test}}` -exclude properties test

if the exclude is not active it will complain about it already exists. Mostly I use the select expression to manipulate data realtime instead of `psCustomObject` for such simple task